# Make Apache2 skip problematic configs?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration, debian-squeeze, httpd.conf

Is there a way to make Apache2 skip configuration files or segments if they lead to errors?

For example, if I have specified a `<VirtualHost></>` but the defined path doesn't exist anymore. Is there something that makes Apache skip the web on restart/reload?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't make apache ignore syntax errors, but you can check for errors in advance ([`httpd -t`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/httpd)) or use "*graceful restart*" (`httpd -k graceful`) during which the check is done, and if there are some, the config doesn't get reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I'm not very fond of very short answers, but in this case I'll make an exception: No, you cannot. If the config is not valid, Apache will tell you.

If a DocumentRoot does not exist that will not lead to an error, just a warning.